# I need to access log files from my network file explorer and write the output

Tags: groovy, ready-api

I  need to access log files from my network folder through Groovy script I'm very new to the groovy scripting. Please help me
Here I'm using Ready API

Expected result is to access my network log file and print the error logs

Answer (score 0):

well,

If you are running the project with a credential(windows user) that has access to the required file, you can access directly.

String fileContents = new File('<>').text

Assert the content as you like.

If you don't have direct access, first you need to find a user that has the access. 
Then you can do one of 2 options:

1. Add a network drive and use the network drive as a local drive.
2. Import libraries that use protocols SMB1 or SMB2 like jcifs, or similar. ( avoid this )

PS: It's not a good practice to use a groovy script to access a network folder, whatever the need that you have.